# making link with .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use javascript for making this link :

```
http://b-c-e.us/bce/Fox.php
```

this is my code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>fid='Fox';</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://b-c-e.us/bce/vs.js"></script>
```

in the vs.js file there is this code :

```
var isMobile={Android:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);},BlackBerry:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);},iOS:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);},Opera:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);},Windows:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);},MacOSX:function(){return navigator.userAgent.match(/Macintosh/i);},any:function(){return(isMobile.Android()||isMobile.BlackBerry()||isMobile.iOS()||isMobile.Opera()||isMobile.Windows());}};var embedded="mobile";if(!isMobile.any()){embedded="desktop";}
document.write('<ifr'+'ame src="http://b-c-e.us/bce/'+fid+' scrolling=no frameborder=0 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true id=thatframe  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen ></ifr'+'ame>');
```

But it doesn't make this link :

```
http://b-c-e.us/bce/Fox.php
```

so which part of my vs.js code should change?

Comment: Seems like you are missing `"` right after `'+fid+'`.

Comment: Change `fid = 'Fox';` to `fid = 'Fox.php';`? (Once you've fixed the issue Eric has pointed out)

Comment: those are definitely the problem, but `'<ifr'+'ame src="...` is a strange and seemingly unnecessary need to separate the iframe tag from the rest of the string

Comment: I tried to add `"` after `'+fid+'` and also changed to `fid = 'Fox.php'` and it fixed now thanks alot